# TRY...CATCH fails to catch exception - string to datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cursor, try-catch

I have to stage some data from load table and because it is SQL Server 2008. I can't use `TRY_CONVERT`, instead I'm loading helper table in cursor with `TRY...CATCH` which later I use to filter out the failed conversion:

```
declare @date varchar(255)
declare @id   varchar(255)

declare c cursor for
    select [ID],[DATE_OF_CREATION]  from dbo.LOAD_TABLE

open c

fetch next from c into @id, @date

while @@Fetch_status <> 0 
begin
    begin try 
        select convert(datetime, right(@date, 8))
    end try
    begin catch
        insert into #error_table(id) select @id
    end catch

    fetch next from c into @id,@date
end

close c
deallocate c
```

Then when I try to select (or insert into staging table) valid data (with ID's that are not in #error_table) it fails.

```
select 
    [ID],
    convert(datetime, right([DATE_OF_CREATION], 8))  
from 
    dbo.LOAD_TABLE
where 
    [ID] not in (select [ID] from #error_table)
```

And it fails with the same error as if the data wasn't filtered out

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

The strangest part about this all is that if i run the above select as a part of the new cursor which i use for data insertion it fails (which is expected), but it doesn't fail in SQL Server 2017 ???!!

So it fails to query data but it successfully executes the cursor with this select.

[EDIT] 
I have found out what was the problem.. In insert cursor I'm joining 
LOAD_TABLE with another fact table, and obviously the join is done first and then filtering by the error table.. It still remains mystery why the execution plan for select query cursor is different than one for simple select.

Comment: so what if you do a SELECT @TEMP_DATE = convert(datetime,right(@date,8)); PRINT(@TEMP_DATE) or similar - what is it getting?  Sounds like it is making something out of the string date somehow.

Comment: I'm getting some weird dates - for '12.4.2018' i'm getting '2018-02-04 00:00:00.000' - but I'm still not sure what specific dates are problem because catch won't catch it :C

Comment: are you definitely going around the loop for all records (try putting valids in their own temp file perhaps, so you can check).  Does doing select @TEMPVAL = convert(datetime, right(@date, 8)) make a difference?

Comment: how about select convert(datetime, right(@date, 8), 104) for that date format - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Comment: If you have 2017 why are you still using 2008? Why not upgrade this instance? Then you can use try_convert and get rid of the error and that loop.

Comment: 2017 is my local server.. Thanks anyway

Comment: The way I would tackle this, is set up some sort of logging by writing results to #temp tables, then you can find an instance of a date that behaves differently in the two queries - is it because the SELECT is somehow sending no data anywhere?  Or do you get a screen full of SELECT results?